# Yii2 Create & use variable with views folder scope

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am trying to create a Yii2 theme, & would like to set a variable that with scope of the entire views folder. For a single page theme I used...

```
$assetDir = Yii::$app->assetManager->getPublishedUrl(
    '@vendor/path/to/assets/folder'
);
```

in `index.php` & I then I accessed it using...

```
<img src="<?= $assetDir ?>/img/image.jpg" alt="">
```

For partials I am able to pass that using...

```
<?= $this->render('_partial.php', ['assetDir' => $assetDir]) ?>
```

I am now wanting to do similar in a theme with multiple pages & cannot find how to do that without setting `$assetDir` in each page. I imagine it would be set in the `main.php` layout.

Comment: The chief purpose of this project is my own learning, & I want to put the variable in the view files because the project is published on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `params` array for this as stated in [Sharing Data among Views](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#sharing-data-among-views).

> The view component provides the params property that you can use to share data among views.
>
> For example, in an about view, you can have the following code which specifies the current segment of the breadcrumbs.
>
> ```
> $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = 'About Us';
> ```
>
> Then, in the layout file, which is also a view, you can display the breadcrumbs using the data passed along params:
>
> ```
> <?= yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs::widget([
> 'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
> ]) ?>
> ```

Comment: So I can set an arbitrary params value like `$this->params['assetDir'] = '@path/to/assets'`? Can that be set in the main layout & accessed from the view files?

Comment: It seems not to work for arbitrary params set in the layout. I just put `$this->params['wombat'] = 'wombat';` (I'm an Aussie, we like wombats) in `main.php` then `<?= $this->params['wombat'] ?>` in `index.php` with the result `yii\base\ErrorException Undefined index: wombat`.

Comment: Since the view is rendered before layout this variable is passed only from view to layout. For a variable shared globally I suggest using static method or common controller property.